# Show that $x<\dfrac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

**Exercise.** The polynomial equation $x^{19}+2x^{17}+x^{15}-x^{2}+x-1=0$ has exactly one positive real root. Show that $x<\dfrac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}$.

**My attempt**

The upper bound is quite sharp. $x<\dfrac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}\approx 0.91700404321...$ According to WolframAlpha $x\approx 0.91700324071...$ So the difference is $\approx 0.0000008025$

I wanted to proceed by assuming $x=\dfrac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ . The expansions are so tedious .
Can I get a result from here by plugging $x=\dfrac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}-\epsilon$ instead of $x$ ?

That is $ \bigg(\dfrac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}-\epsilon\bigg)^{19}+2\bigg(\frac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}-\epsilon\bigg)^{17}+\bigg(\frac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}-\epsilon\bigg)^{15}-\bigg(\frac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}-\epsilon\bigg)^{2}+\frac{\sqrt [8]{128}}{2}-\epsilon-1=0 $

My idea is showing that $\epsilon>0$ by opening the parentheses using Binomial theorem.  Am I on the right track ?

Comment: What about numerical root finding?

Comment: Is it useful the bound is 2^(7/8-1) = 2^(-1/8)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

collect $u =  x^2 + 1 $   as $ \; \; \; x^{15}  u^2 - u + x = 0$  so

$$  x^2 + 1 = \frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4 x^{16} \;}}{2 x^{15}   } $$

and you cannot have $4 x^{16}  > 1.$

Also $4 x^{16}  = 1$  does not work. Then you get $(2x)(2x^{15}) = 1,$  so $x^2 + 1 = 2x,$  however $x \neq 1$

Comment: In other words (avoiding square roots): $1-4x^{16} = (2x^{15}u-1)^2 \ge 0$, and $=$ is not possible.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how you solved this, and then it hit me.  You didn't actually solve this.  Instead, you are from the future, and you simply got Gauss to solve it, and then, in this parallel timeline, reported the answer on MathSE.